# Cambiar texto con transición JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy intentando hacer que un texto cambie de valor con una transición, el texto se me cambia, pero lo que no sé es cómo hacer la transición, lo he intentado de muchas maneras pero no me sale. Esta es la función:

```
function rotar() {
        var indice = 0;
        frases = new Array();
        frases[0] = "Frase 1";
        frases[1] = "Frase 2";
        frases[2] = "Frase 3";
        frases[3] = "Frase 4";

        indice = Math.random()*(frases.length);
        indice = Math.floor(indice);

        if (indice == frases.length) {
            indice = 0;
        }
        $("#frase-celebre").html(frases[indice]);//Esta es la frase que quiero que haga transición
        indice++;
        setTimeout("rotar();", 5000);

    }
```

Este es el HTML:

`<p id="frase-celebre">“Lo más magnífico de las fotografías es que pueden producir imágenes que incitan la emoción basadas en un único tema”.</p>`

Lo he intentado muchas veces con algo parecido a esto:

`$("#frase-celebre").html(frases[indice]).fadeOut( "slow" )`

pero nada... Muchas gracias por la ayuda!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo donde funciona la funcion $.fadeOut("slow") bajo las condiciones que solicitabas.

```js
$('body').on("click","#frase-celebre",function(){
rotar();
}) 
    
    function rotar(){
            var indice = 0;
        frases = new Array();
        frases[0] = "Cerrando 1...";
        frases[1] = "Cerrando 2...";
        frases[2] = "Cerrando 3...";
        frases[3] = "Cerrando 4...";

        indice = Math.random()*(frases.length);
        indice = Math.floor(indice);

        if (indice == frases.length) {
            indice = 0;
        }
        $("#frase-celebre").html(frases[indice]).fadeOut("slow");
        indice++;
        setTimeout('rotar()', 5000);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<p id="frase-celebre">“Lo más magnífico de las fotografías es que pueden producir imágenes que incitan la emoción basadas en un único tema”.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ya he editado la pregunta con el HTML. Sí sí, están todas las librerías incluidas.

Comment: Esto es un comentario, no una respuesta

Comment: No puedo comentar debido a mi reputación @CristianS9

Comment: @Csc99 ahí tienes el ejemplo funcionando. Espero haberte ayudado.